# How to configure digitalocean space in kubernetes

Tags: kubernetes, digital-ocean

I'm trying to configure external storage like S3 / digital-ocean as Persistent Volume and access the same by PVC. I have configured the .yaml for PVC method in Kubernetes but can't create.
pls anyone help this

Comment: Sorry, this is too vague to get a good answer. I would try giving more specifics about what problem you have and the error you are getting.

Comment: how to configure external storage like S3,digital-ocean space in .yaml file

Comment: Please share the .yml created so far..

Answer (score 2):

You can use DO spaces (s3 storage) as a PVC with read-write-many
https://github.com/ctrox/csi-s3

Comment: Status of this project: "This is still very experimental and should not be used in any production environment" Sou I wouldn't recommend it for production use.